# How to check for space in android when creating files or saving images?

Tags: android, image

In android, I create txt files and save images too. But I'm not sure it is safe because I don't really check for space before saving. Does anyone have code here or know a tutorial that checks for space?

I just have this when saving images. Can I assume that if there isn't any space, it will throw an IOException, or do I need other code to do this?

Thanks

```
private static void imageSaverHelper(File file, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is not enough space, you will get an exception. There's really no other sensible way to handle this. Since the image is being compressed, there's no way to accurately predict how much space it will take without actually doing the compression.

Even if you could get an accurate measurement of the space it would take, there might be something else going on in the background that uses up that space before you get a chance to write your file.

The best approach is to write your file but be prepared to handle exceptions.

Comment: is IOException the only exception i need to handle?

Comment: Yes. But your Java compiler will tell you if anything you call might throw something else.